# No resources found when setting up AWS WAF ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, acl, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-waf

I'm trying to set up an ACL for a load balancer, but it does not show up in the `Associated AWS resources` section when creating the web ACL.

[image: create ACL dashboard]

The `Resource Type` is `Regional resources`, and the region is the same as my (network) load balancer (us-west-2).

This is the load balancer config:
[image]

Note: I have admin access so this isn't a permission issue, at least not with my IAM user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note how the first screenshot is showing a list of **Application** Load Balancers, and your second screenshot is of a **Network** Load Balancer. AWS WAF is not supported for Network Load Balancers, only Application Load Balancers.